# How to retrieve parent page's $node variable in a block using module_invoke()?

Tags: drupal, drupal-blocks

I'm using `module_invoke()` to include a block and I need in this block to read a value contained in my parent content type page. So how can I get the `$node` variable in my block from the view?

Code I'm using:

```
<?php
    $block = module_invoke('my_blocks', 'block', 'view', 7);
    print $block['content'];
?>
```

Now I need to access `$node` in "my_blocks" and the variable is empty. What can I do to get it?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

little fix to drupal way:

```
    function InMODULE_or_InTHEME_get_current_node() {
      if ((arg(0) == 'node') && (is_numeric(arg(1))) && (!arg(2))) return node_load(arg(1));
      return null;
    }
```

*Comments: node_load cache nodes, so don't worry about perfomance.
 "!arg(2)" is checking for just you don't in node edit mode (or something like).*

Comment: menu_get_object() will save you a bit of typing if you're using Drupal 6 and up.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module or [chaos tools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) can help with that, but here's how I did the same thing recently:

```
function myModule_get_current_node() {
    $path_arr = explode('/', $_GET['q']);
    if ($path_arr[0] == 'node') $result = node_load($path_arr[1]);
    else $result = null;
    return $result;
}
```